# Finding median in AVL tree

Tags: median, avl-tree

I have an AVL tree in which I want to return the median element in O(1).
I know I can save a pointer to it every time I insert new element without changing the runtime of the insertion (by saving the size of the subtrees and traversing until I find the n/2'th size subtree).
But I want to know if I can do this using the fact that in every insertion the median shifts "to the right", and in every deletion the median shifts "to the left".
In a more general manner: How can I keep track of the i'th element in an AVL tree using predecessor and successor?

Answer (score 1):

Given an AVL (self balanced binary search tree), find the median. Remember you can't just take the root element even if the tree is balanced because even with the tree balanced you don't know if the median is exactly the root element on a left or right son. Iterative algorithm used to find the median of an AVL. This algorithm is based on a property of every AVL tree, you can get a sorted collection containing the elements of this tree using an in order traversal. Using this property we can get a sorted collection of nodes and then find the median. The complexity order of this algorithm is O(N) in time and space terms where N is the number of nodes in the tree.

```
public class AvlTreeMedian {

  BinaryTreeInOrder binaryTreeInOrder;

  public AvlTreeMedian() {
    this.binaryTreeInOrder = new BinaryTreeInOrder();
  }

  public double find(BinaryNode<Integer> root) {
    if (root == null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("You can't pass a null binary tree to this method.");
    }

    List<BinaryNode<Integer>> sortedElements = binaryTreeInOrder.getIterative(root);
    double median = 0;
    if (sortedElements.size() % 2 == 0) {
      median = (sortedElements.get(sortedElements.size() / 2).getData() + sortedElements.get(
          sortedElements.size() / 2 - 1).getData()) / 2;
    } else {
      median = sortedElements.get(sortedElements.size() / 2).getData();
    }
    return median;
  }
}
```